# Using Wizard addon

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

Dear friends I'm new of vaadin and I would want to use wizard add-on in my vaadin application.
Now my trouble is that I don't have a fix number of steps. I try to explain in a better way, I have the following optionGroup

[image]

Then when i choose fixed size I don't have a problem because I can do this

```
// instantiate the Wizard
 Wizard wizard = new Wizard();

// add some steps that implement the WizardStep interface
wizard.addStep(new FirstStep());
wizard.addStep(new SecondStep());
wizard.addStep(new ThirdStep());
wizard.addStep(new FourthStep());
```

while when i choose the dynamic size, I don't know the exact number of step, but is the user that while running the wizard can add additional step or not.

Is this possible with the wizard add-on?

Comment: How does the system (or user) know the number of steps?

Comment: My user receive some  paper documents, and according with the number of this documenst would want the number of step in the Wizard

Comment: for (i=0; i < numberOnPage; i++) {wizard.addStep(....)}

Comment: But sometimes  user has to do some operations where can need open others step, Can i do this with wizard addon?

Comment: You can call addStep(...) at any time you wish, even when the wizard is already "in progress..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to add/remove steps while running the wizard.

```
wizard.addStep(...)
wizard.removeStep(...)
```

You can see here in this demo: 
http://teemu.virtuallypreinstalled.com/wizards-for-vaadin/#intro

Source code:
https://github.com/tehapo/WizardsForVaadin/tree/master/wizards-for-vaadin-demo/src/main/java/org/vaadin/teemu/wizards